# List locations near by to a lat, lon point from stored lat, lon in database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-maps, gis, geojson

I have `[lat, lon]` pairs of different locations stored in *MongoDb*. Now I want to compare a certain coordinates pair by distance like in circle of *2 km* from that point and want to take results of all from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at [geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/geoNear/#command-syntax) command.

Generic example is the following:

```
db.runCommand(
   {
     geoNear: "places", // Your target collection
     near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.9667, 40.78 ] }, // Point coordinates
     spherical: true, // 2dsphere index required for using this option
     query: { yourField: "someFilterVale" }, // Additional regular filtering
     maxDistance: 2000 // Maximum distance in meters/radians
   }
)
```

> `minDistance` is also available for querying

For this purpose you should have **[2d](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2d/)** or **[2dsphere](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/)** index in your collection.

> Also there is a [$geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) aggregation.